# All settings available for \pscircle (PSTricks) command

Tags: pstricks

The general form of the `\pscircle` is

```
\pscircle*[settings](x0,y0){radius}
```

Is there a way to known all available settings?

Comment: Good question! IMHO you are asking for something like a list of parameters, supported by `\pscircle`. I do not know such a list and unfortunately the pstricks manual neither provides such a list nor does it explicitly document for each parameter which commands do support them. So reading the manual is not enough. For some parameters it is obvious, whether  `\pscircle` supports them or not. But for some parameters and at least for a pstricks novice it is indeed not always obvious.

Comment: Everything which is valid for lines and filled curves. See documentation: chapter 2 and 5 for "Basic graphics parameters"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the line:

```
linewidth
linecolor
linestyle
dash
dotsep
doubleline
doublesep
doublecolor
dimen
border
bordercolor
shadow
shadowsize
shadowangle
shadowcolor
```

for the filling:

```
fillcolor
fillstyle
shapealpha
hatchsep
hatchsepinc
hatchwidth
hatchwidthinc
hatchcolor
hatchangle
addfillstyle
opacity
strokeopacity
```

See also http://www.siart.de/typografie/pstricks-referenz.pdf  (only in German)

Comment: Good question and good answer. +1.